# Linking Lame.h with PHP extension

Tags: php, c, lame, php-internals

I'm trying to develop my first php extension. It uses Lame , so I've installed liblame-dev
lame.h is located at `/usr/include/lame/`

In my config.m4

```
  LIBNAME=lame
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($LIBNAME)
```

It builds, but something goes wrong at apache startup

```
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/myextension.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/myextension.so: 
undefined symbol: lame_init in Unknown on line 0
```

**SOLUTION**

correct rows config.m4 for me, are

PHP_SUBST(MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)

PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(mp3lame, 1,MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)

Comment: If [that](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/) helps..